# Unsure of how to handle a NullReferenceException

Tags: mysql, vb.net, list, nullreferenceexception

When my form for creating a group of students loads up, I receive a `NullReferenceException` for seemingly no reason. This is the code that handles the form loading:

```
Private Sub AddGroupForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For i As Integer = 0 To Form1.lstStudents.Items.Count - 1
        lstStudentList.Items.Add(Form1.lstStudents.Items.Item(i))
    Next
    tempStudentList.AddRange(Form1.mainStudentList)
    btnAllOut.Enabled = False
    btnOneOut.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

The `mainStudentList` referred to is a list that is populated upon loading by using MySQL:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;database=new_project;port=3306;password=********;")
        conn.Open()
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM students WHERE deleted=0 ORDER BY lastName;", conn)
        Dim dataSet As New DataSet()
        Dim dataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "students")
        Dim dataTable As DataTable = dataSet.Tables("students")
        For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
            Dim newStudent As New Student
            newStudent.intIDNum = row.Item("passCode")
            newStudent.strFirstName = row.Item("firstName")
            newStudent.strLastName = row.Item("lastName")
            newStudent.chrGender = row.Item("gender")
            newStudent.dateDOB = row.Item("dateOfBirth")
            newStudent.intAge = CInt(Today.Year - newStudent.dateDOB.Year)
            newStudent.intYearGroup = row.Item("yearGroup")
            newStudent.intSkillLevel = SByte.Parse(row.Item("skillLevel"))
            mainStudentList.Add(newStudent)
            lstStudents.Items.Add(newStudent.nameConcat(newStudent.strFirstName, newStudent.strLastName))
        Next
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

The specific exception occurs when the `tempStudentList` attempts to load the values in the `mainStudentList`. Specifically, it states that "Object reference not set to instance of an Object".

Comment: Is it possible that the student DOB filed could be null or empty for a student? If so, you would want to use `ISNULL` to check and adjust the value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure mainStudentList has been initialized first.

c#

```
List<Student> mainStudentList = new List<Student>();
```

VB.Net

```
Dim mainStudentList As New List(Of Student)()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly to do here? `mainStudentList` is initialized and made Public in `Form1` so that doesn't seem to be the problem, as far as I can see.

Comment: Post the error message and the stack trace if you have it.